# How debug segfault at realloc()?

Tags: c, gdb, realloc

I'm at a loss. Here is what happens in gdb:

```
571             void *aux = realloc(cs->body, new_size);
(gdb) p cs->body
$6 = 0x627b20 "POST /upload HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.0e zlib/1.2.5 c-ares/1.7.5 libidn/1.22 libssh2/1.2.9\r\nHost: localhost:2001\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Le"...
(gdb) n
*** glibc detected *** /home/pc/bin/main: realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000627b20 ***
```

...far down after the backtrace and memory map (which I don't know how to interpret):

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7660d95 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

How is this possible? I printed `cs->body` right before the realloc call, and it looks fine right? How can it be an invalid pointer, but still contain characters just fine?
How can I debug this segfault?

Comment: This type of bug is often caused somewhere / some time before the actual crash happens.  I agree with @Oli: I'd go straight to valgrind to investigate this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereferencing invalid pointers invokes **undefined behaviour**, which means that anything could happen, including the behaviour that you're observing.  If I had to guess, I'd say that either:

- your pointer really is invalid (it wasn't obtained from `malloc`, or you've already `free`d it, or you've modified it accidentally.
- you've overflowed a buffer somewhere, and trashed `malloc`'s behind-the-scenes metadata.

I would suggest running your application in something like Valgrind, which is designed to help track down memory issues.

Comment: it seems like I wrote over the end of the malloc'ed memory, and that later somehow made realloc crash as well. I didn't know malloc has metadata behind the scenes and presumably realloc then interacts with that..? I'm not crashing anymore, so that seems to have done it

Comment: @Blub: Yes, a common implementation of `malloc` is to allocate more space than you request, and then place metadata outside the "visible" region.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities:

- The memory is valid, but not obtained via malloc or realloc (string literal, global, static, automatic memory, memory obtained via mmap() or via shm*)
- the memory has been obtained via malloc, but the pointer is not the exact pointer to the beginning of the object (the one you got from malloc() You might have skipped initial white, or your pointer points into a structure or 2d array, etc.
- you have corrupted your memory by using an incorrect offset or pointer *anywhere in the program*

In your case choosing between the options (1,2) and 3 above is easy: you can visually inspect how the "cs->body" pointer got its value. If is was really obtained via malloc et.al, only option 3 is open. Without using valgrind, the only way to find spurious overwrites is to (temporally) rollback the latest changes in the source.